# QSpacerItem changeSize attracts bug

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I'm creating a calendar app and just finished the appointment view and edit. Basicly it's a `QVBoxLayout` with the viewlayout and editlayout in it and I hide and show either the view or edit using signals.

That works just fine, there is 1 issue: in the viewlayout I have a QSpacerItem for some extra spacing and in order to remove the space when viewing the edit-part I change its size.

Like so

```
if( show_view_hide_edit )
    spacer->changeSize(1, 60, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed );
else
    spacer->changeSize(0, 0, QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed );
```

This code works when the widget shows, and when I swap it to "edit". When I switch it back to view and then go back to edit the spacing is at the top of my screen. It shouldnt really be there. Image shows what happens. ([link to image for size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44oZj.jpg))

[image]

Comment: try to place the second changeSize before the if: `spacer->changeSize(0, 0, QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed );
if( show_view_hide_edit )
    spacer->changeSize(1, 60, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed );
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the construction code of your widget it is a little hard to guess, what is going on. Have you tried to insert / remove the SpacerItems with QBoxLayout::insertSpacing ( int index, int size ) and QLayout::removeItem ( QLayoutItem * item )?

And did you call QLayout::invalidate () after changing the size?

Comment: Awesome, thanks. After the resizing I called the `main_layout->invalidate();` and that fixed it all!